# no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xe

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I found problem with ojdbc drivrr while connecting  to my project.even i put the ojdbc14.jar on classpath  but still  it doesnt work for me. i must be thankful in advance  for letting me to get rid off this . this is `myspringcfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="fetchBean" class="com.prime.datasource.FetchBean">
    <property name="DataSource" ref ="ds" />
</bean>

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.3.44:1521:xe" />  
    <property name="username" value="harish" />  
    <property name="password" value="password" />  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

this  is `fetchbean.java`

```
package com.prime.datasource;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * @author agubbala
 */
public class FetchBean implements Fetch {

    //Constants for Queries
    String NAMESQL = "SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID = ?";
    String SALSQL = "SELECT SAL FROM EMP WHERE EMPID = ?";
    String DEPTSQL = "SELECT DEPTNO FROM ENO WHERE EMPID = ?";

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource (org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.prime.datasource.Fetch#fetchEmpName(int)
     */
    @Override
    public String fetchEmpName(int empId) {
        return getData(NAMESQL, empId);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.prime.datasource.Fetch#fetchEmpSal(int)
     */
    @Override
    public String fetchEmpSal(int empId) {
        return getData(SALSQL, empId);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.prime.datasource.Fetch#fetchEmpDeptNo(int)
     */
    @Override
    public String fetchEmpDeptNo(int empId) {
        return getData(DEPTSQL, empId);
    }

    //My Bussiness Logic
    public String getData(String sqlQuery, int empId) {
        if (dataSource != null) {
            try {
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                stmt.setInt(1, empId);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next())
                    return rs.getString(0);
                else
                    return "";

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else
            return null;
    }

}
```

this is `fetch.java`

```
public interface Fetch {
    public String fetchEmpName(int empId);
    public String fetchEmpSal(int empId);
    public String fetchEmpDeptNo(int empID);
}
```

this is `fetchclient.java`

```
public class FetchClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystemResource cfg = new FileSystemResource(".\\src\\SpringCfg.xml");
        XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(cfg);
        Fetch fetchObj = (Fetch) factory.getBean("fetchBean");

        System.out.println("Name of EMP: " + fetchObj.fetchEmpName(100));
        System.out.println("Name of EMP: " + fetchObj.fetchEmpSal(100));
        System.out.println("Name of EMP: " + fetchObj.fetchEmpDeptNo(100));


    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the jdbc driver placed? which version of oracle you are using?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: `ojdbc14.jar` is totally outdated. It is intended for Java 1.4, not for any modern Java version. The number in Oracle's filename is the target *Java version*, not the driver's version

Comment: i already  searched for ojdbc7.jar but  i found it nowhere. jdk1.7 and oracle 10g is running on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

With oracle 10g and jdk 1.7, you need to have `ojdbc7` driver which you can find [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html). You need to have it in your classpath. One more thing, replace `<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />`

by

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
```

this is the correct class that have to be loaded for JDBC operations on Oracle 10g using thin client.